# how to disble or make convenient workspaces in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, workspaces

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. How can I disable workspace in 12.04?

If there is no way to do that, how can I quickly switch my focus between different workspaces, without clicking the clumsy "workspace switcher"?

For example, I saw Mac users can glide their fingers on the touchpad to switch workspace to the right or left, while  Ubuntu 12.04 has four workspaces on the top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right, and I haven't found a way to move my focus between them by touchpad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hold the `Ctrl` and `Alt` keys while pressing the Arrow keys, to switch between workspaces.

To use touchpad gestures, you must have a touchpad which supports multitouch to be able to do such gestures.

Comment: my laptop is Thinkpad T400. Is its touchpad multitouch?

Answer (score 1):

Use Ubuntu tweak and enable a hot corner for the workspaces.
In my setup, taking my mouse cursor to the right bottom corner of the screen spreads out the workspaces and you just click on the one you want.

**Setup**
"tweaks" -> "workspaces"
In the bottom right corner, choose show workspaces.
You can even choose show windows for the top right corner to make switching windows easy.

[image]